# Ag-grid drag and drop doesn't work after sorting rows

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

After sorting my rows on Ag-grid-react, drag and drop stops working. Before sorting, drag and drop is all set and working well.

postSort API does not seem to have something to achieve what I need, reset the row or even set draggable just like for selection.

```
postSort={nodes => nodes.forEach(n => n.setRowSelectable(true))}
```

I've tried also to use

```
postSort={nodes => nodes.forEach(n => n.setDragging(true))}
```

but that would actually start the dragging for all the rows instead

I want the drag and drop to keep working when row is clicked after sorting them.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. if you are facing a similar issue where you want to enable drag after a sort you need to disable the sort like this:

gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({ defaultState: { sort: null } });

this will bring back the drag&drop to the columns you had it prior to the sort.

Still trying to find a way to tell the grid to reorganize its indexes so we can keep the sort and enable the drag at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *Managed Dragging* (`rowDragManaged={true}`), you cannot drag any rows anywhere else because doing that will break the order of the rows as stated in the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/#managed-dragging)

> The logic for managed dragging is simple and has the following
> constraints:
>
> - Does not work when sorting is applied. This is because the sort order
>   of the rows depends on the data and moving the data would break the
>   sort order.

Comment: How do I access grid API from an onRowDragMove Event ? The unmanaged examples are not clear to me

Comment: Most ag-grid [events](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f011ffb0ad989acc9e43c9eb075c98e01e264668/community-modules/core/typings/events.d.ts#L29-L32) have `GridApi` (`e.api`) and `ColumnApi` (`e.columnApi`) attached to it. @PedroSilveira

Comment: thanks for your very beneficial help. However I wasn't able to configure unmanaged dragging. Opened another question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020843/how-to-use-unmanaged-drag-on-ag-grid

Comment: @PedroSilveira I'll have a look tomorrow. Your question is a hard one because what you want is not supported in agGrid, so no promise.

Comment: @PedroSilveira... any luck with this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Yogesh no... I ended up using react-beautiful-dnd. Wasn't a breeze to implement it either. https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/patterns/multi-drag.md good luck! :)

Comment: @PedroSilveira... I am using angular.. looks like I will also need to explore something else