# How to use unmanaged drag on ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there any examples that show how to make a single column grid sortable and draggable? (unmanaged dragging)
The onRowDragMove event doesn't fire properly.

Each row is an object with only two key-value pairs: name and path. This is what I've tried

```
   function onRowDrag(e) {
    console.log('row drag()')
    let movingNode = e.node;
    let overNode = e.overNode;
    let rowStore = e.api.getRenderedNodes();
    console.dir(rowStore);
  
    let rowNeedsToMove = movingNode !== overNode;
  
    if (rowNeedsToMove) {
      // the list of rows we have is data, not row nodes, so extract the data
      let movingData = movingNode.data;
      let overData = overNode.data;
  
      let fromIndex = rowStore.indexOf(movingData);
      let toIndex = rowStore.indexOf(overData);
  
      let newStore = rowStore.slice();
      moveInArray(newStore, fromIndex, toIndex);
  
      rowStore = newStore;
      e.api.setRowData(newStore);
  
      e.api.clearFocusedCell();
    }
  
    function moveInArray(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
      var element = arr[fromIndex];
      arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
      arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "unmanaged dragging" and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Viqas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980902) is some context. They want the grid rows to be draggable when in ascending/descending mode

Comment: I actually can't drag in unmanaged mode even before sorting. My app has an immutable store (react useState variable). I made some progress, I believe that if I'm able to drag rows before sorting, it would work afterwards too. The examples on docs are just not clear enough. I'm not sure onRowDragMove is the best method for me. I usually have at least 5-10 rows

Comment: @PedroSilveira when in managed dragging, you cannot subsequently drag / drop after a sort or filter operation. This is a limitation of managed drag & drop. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-dragging/#managed-dragging. To overcome this you would have to use unmanaged drag & drop.